# Cant able to run with connected device (minSdk(API 15) > deviceSdk(API 1))-Android

Tags: android, android-studio, emulation

I have connected a device with version lollipop 5.1. I just created a project and tried to run that it shows

Exclamatory symbol with (minSdk(API 15) > deviceSdk(API 1))

What is device Sdk ...

Note i m using Android Studio 2.0

Build.gradle file:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "c.sam.com.helpdesksample"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
```

Below is my image showing error
[image]

Comment: Try following:
1. Check whether the developer options on the device are ON
2. If you'll get a pop-up asking permission to connenct to this device, accept that. You will get this pop-up on mobile home screen when you'll connect device to PC if you are connecting it for the first time.

Comment: @Dhaval well i m using emulator, and Developer options on device is ON .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all ur attention friends,
I have found solution

need to stop adb and run ...

I have done this,

> ctrl+Alt+delete (Task Manager)--> Process--> adb.exe*32 To End Process (pressed) and end process
>   Then, Again i run the project i does not showing the

(minSdk(API 15) > deviceSdk(API 1))

Works well now...